# How do I escape dynamic text in <title> tag inside header using Nuxt JS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have integrated WordPress API with a Nuxt based website. It is using below code to show blog Post title fetched from wordpress.

```
head() {
    return{
      title: this.post.title.rendered
    }
  }
```

But the problem is, when we have special characters e.g. single quote, it renders them as it is inside  tag.
See below example

```
original text : Let&#8217;s begin
text to render : Let's begin
but it renders : Let&#8217;s begin
```

This works fine with `<v-html>` if I want to display it on a page somewhere but how do I do the same inside title tag?

Comment: your `original text`, `text to render` and `but it renders` look the same in question, please update the question

Comment: ah sorry, done.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const decodeString = (str) => {
  let decoded_string;
  try {
    decoded_string = decodeURI(str);
  } catch (error) {
    // dont decode and just use raw string
    decoded_string = str;
  }
  const replace_chars = {
    "&amp;": "&",
    "&#8217;": ","
  };
  return Object.entries(replace_chars).reduce(
    (result_str, entry_arr) => result_str.replace(...entry_arr),
    decoded_string
  );
};

console.log(decodeString("Let&#8217;s begin"));

/* 
PS: you may not need decodeURI() call in your code sample, But this function can be generic and keep updating the replace_chars.

head() {
    return{
      title: decodeString(this.post.title.rendered)
    }
  }
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it using "he" library
https://github.com/mathiasbynens/he